# How to convert JSON format to a string in C++

Tags: c++, json, parsing

### Convert JSON format to a string in C++

Have been searching for a solution to convert JSON to a plain string,
but can't find anything remotely suitable.

For example, I have the following data:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

but need it in the following format:

```
key1: "value1"
key2: "value2"
```

Would somebody perhaps know of a solution that can achieve this?
Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Comment: There's no built in support for JSON in C++. So you really need to explain what you mean by 'JSON format'. Do you mean that you have a string with those characters? If so you need a JSON parser, see previous comment. On the other hand if you have some typed data, with the structure indicated above. If so then the question is unanswerable without knowing more about the types you are using (although if this is the case then the answer, whatever it is, is probably going to be trivial).

Comment: Hi John, I understand that C++ has no native support for JSON
and as my question outlines, I have the following:

    {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
    
    and want to convert it into:

    key1: "value1"
    key2: "value2" 
    
and github.com/nlohmann/json does not seem to do what I want to achieve.

Comment: Would [YAML](https://yaml.org/) be an acceptable output format? Alternatively you have to walk the datastructure yourself. Not every exact little problem is completely pre-made.

Comment: Hi Botje, unfortunately YAML is not what I require. 
I am simply trying to "strip" double quotes, commas and curly braces from a JSON response I get from a REST API.
for instance {"hello": "world"} -> hello: "world"

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
It seems that I am the only person in the world who gets JSON formatted data from a "REST API" and wants to store it in a variable for further processing in C++.

There seems to be NO solution that converts JSON

```json
{
 "variable1": "data1"
}
```

into this:

```json
variable1 = "data1";
```

Even though it is unbelievable, but I guess I have to reinvent the wheel after all and code this myself.

Comment: `variable1 = "data1";` as an evaluated C++ statement is indeed not possible from a runtime string, but that isn't what your question asked for.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to create "dynamic" variables name from the json data? C++ is not a scripting language and that task is impossible, what do you mean **reinvent the wheel**? Is this an answer to your question?